# Can SharePoint access other systems REST Services using SharePoint Designer & BCS?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

In our organization we have web HR system, we can access this system using REST API and read data from it. We need to allow users access this data form SharePoint.

Can we do this task using SharePoint Designer & BCS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BCS framework does support an OData-backed data source. (OData describes the payload format - REST desribes the URI naming scheme.)

However, you cannot create a BCS Model for an OData data source using SPD. Visual Studio will automatically generate one, or you can code it by hand. In either case, you can use the BCS Service Application web interface to upload the model.